# How to group a datetime column by year?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe with a column of this format : `datetime64[ns]`
I want to group by rows by year. The dates are of this format: `2019-01-08 02:27:17`
I unsuccessfully tried

```
df1=df.groupby([(df.modification_datetime.year)]).sum()
```

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'

Do you know how to solve that?

EDIT :

The solution is

```
df1=df.groupby(df.modification_datetime.dt.year).sum()
```

We don't need the brackets!

Comment: `df.modification_datetime.dt.year` i.e `df1=df.groupby(df.modification_datetime.dt.year).sum()`

Comment: I have this error : "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values". Maybe it's the date format that is not correct ? I mean, I never deal with this format datetime64[ns] before, maybe we cannot group by year or month ?

Comment: so convert them to datetime first `df['modification_datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df['modification_datetime'])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need all of those brackets, and you need to use the `dt` accessor to extract the year from the date:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.modification_datetime.dt.year).sum()
```

Comment: This has been eluded to in a comment, but I am sharing this as an answer with a short explanation.

Comment: Thanks it work perfectly! I was sure we need to use bracket but not haha... Thanks a lot and have a good day :) !

Comment: @Mouss1995 That syntax is not incorrect, those brackets don't result in any error; `dt` accessor made it work. Unnecessary is a better word

Comment: @MustafaAydın It's my lack of clarity; I have amended my answer accordingly.